# Have any one tried using ZK Mobile for Android?

Tags: android, zk

I want to develop an web app for Android phone using ZK(I am pretty good in it). Have any one tried using it, I have referred to ZK documentation but I am not able to find much help.

Comment: [Here](http://jtechnoprojects.blogspot.in/2012/12/vaadin-touchkit-vs-zk-mobile-vs.html) are more details about ZK Mobile, and comparison of it with similar technogoies too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking ZK web application with webview. 
Yes , ZK do test it with andriod webview, so I think it's fine .

You could test it with ZK demo , and report all the bugs you find if any.

http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/grid?zkn=1

About the performance , I think that depends your device,
for my phone (HTC EVO 3D), it's acceptable.

But it's still better to build a mobile version for mobile phone (no matter using ZK or not) to get better user experience.

Since the use-case/screen-resolution is quite different between desktop and mobile .

Answer (score 2):

It won't work well since it's a product ZK released 2-3 years ago, I am not suggesting you to try it.

Comment: evidence to back your claim...?

Comment: The evidence is that I am a senior ZK developer.
ZK mobile is designed for J2ME , the ZK mobile for andriod is out of date for a long time and it only support Button, Frame, Label, Image, Textbox components. Just to be honest , it's not a working solution for andriod now. It could still be extended if you know ZK well, but I don't suggest to use it.

Comment: k...I that case what if I use android Webview to access the ZUL (url I have tried it).
Is it a good idea to use same Web app for desktop and android phone? I am more interested in the performance and speed to access the web app. 
Note: pls submit it as answer!